# What is the best way to access Quasar (or Vue 3) app name variable?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework

How do I implement something like this in [Quasar](https://quasar.dev/) without redefining the variable in each component:

```
<template>
    <div>Welcome to {{ APP_NAME }}.</div>
</template>
```

My app was setup using Quasar CLI which asked for an app name during setup, so I imagine that is stored somewhere as a global variable or something I can access.

Failing that, maybe Vue 3 has a way of doing this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quasar doesn't use a main.js file explicitly.  Most of the suggested answers won't work when creating a project using quasar cli.  Using quasar.config.js might work but it's still not exactly the right place to do it.

Since you used the quasar cli you need to add a boot file with quasar new boot.

This will generate the file ezglobals.js in your src/boot folder:
`quasar new boot ezglobals`

Your code in your ezglobals.js file will look something like this after editing:

```
import { boot } from 'quasar/wrappers'
export default boot(({ app }) => {
  app.config.globalProperties.$APP_NAME = 'The name of your app';
})
```

Finally in quasar.config.js add ezglobals.js to the boot array:

```
...
boot: [
      'ezglobals.js'
    ]
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Yo can create [global variable](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-config.html#globalproperties) in Vue 3:

```
const globalVariable = 'app name'
app.config.globalProperties.$appName = globalVariable
```

and then show it in any template like:

```
<template>
 <div>Welcome to {{ $appName }}.</div>
</template>
```

Comment: I might be daft, but I don't know where to put that first code. It seems Quasar dosen't come with a main.js file if that is where you expected that to do.

Comment: @TinyTiger hey mate , not sure about Quasar, try like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50823340/with-vue-cli-where-do-i-declare-my-global-variables), just  convert it to Vue3

Comment: [the documentation](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/boot-files#axios) recommends a boot file.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways how you could do it.

The name you specified during project creation using Quasar CLI is stored in your package.json file (`"name": "…"`).
You can access package.json vars like that:

```
process.env.npm_package_name
```

Here is a link with more info about it:
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/scripts#packagejson-vars

To make this globally available you can create a boot file specifying a global variable.

Here you can read more on how to create and use boot files (boot is a folder in your project created by quasar cli): https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/boot-files

Here you can find more info to define global variables: https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-config.html#globalproperties

Answer (score 0):

You should import Quasar in main.js

```
import { useQuasar } from 'Quasar'


createApp(App).use(Quasar, { config: {} }).mount('#app')
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand how that would give me an app name varible to use inside a SFC template.

Comment: There's no `main.js`. Only `App.vue` and `quasar.conf.js`.

Comment: @BrianCannard thats a relatively new thing. The answer isn't wrong. Its just not right for new versions of Quasar

Comment: Relatively new thing? It's been that way since v1 afaik, which is years ago (?). This question is about Vue3 & Quasar 2, which has always setup this way.

Answer (score 0):

not exactly global -
you have to *make it available* in every component you want to use it.

define some env options in your `quasar.config.js` file:

```js
const packageInfo = require('./package.json')

const { configure } = require('quasar/wrappers');

module.exports = configure(function (ctx) {
    return {
        // ....
        build: {
            // ....
            env: {
                // https://forum.quasar-framework.org/topic/6853/auto-generate-a-build-number-in-spa/15?_=1653270667151
                // https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/handling-process-env#caveats
                // TEST: "42",
                appinfo: {
                    name: packageInfo.name,
                    version: packageInfo.version,
                    productName: packageInfo.productName,
                    description: packageInfo.description,
                    projectUrl: packageInfo.projectUrl,
                    previewUrl: packageInfo.previewUrl,
                },
            },
        },
        // ....
    }
});
```

than you need to include something like this in `YourComponent.vue` file:

```
<template>
    <q-page
        class="flex column"
        style="align-items: center;"
    >
        <section>
            <h4>{{ appinfo.productName }}</h4>
            <p>
                version: v{{ appinfo.version }}
            </p>
            <p>
                {{ appinfo.description }}<br>
                find the project repository at <br>
                <a
                    target="_blank"
                    :href="appinfo.projectUrl"
                >
                    {{ appinfo.projectUrl }}
                </a>
            </p>
            <p>
                a live preview version is hosted at<br>
                <a
                    target="_blank"
                    :href="appinfo.previewUrl"
                >
                    {{ appinfo.previewUrl }}
                </a>
            </p>
        </section>
    </q-page>
</template>

<script setup>
// https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/handling-process-env#caveats
// console.log(process.env.TEST)
const appinfo = process.env.appinfo
</script>
```

or for the script part the older way:

```js
<script>
export default {
    name: 'AboutPage',
    data () {
        // https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/handling-process-env#caveats
        // console.log(process.env.TEST)
        return {
            appinfo: process.env.appinfo,
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I recommend to do something like

```
import myNiceThing from "mything-vue3";
app.use(myNiceThing);
```

though that is a little unreliable.

Comment: You might have to add some explanations on what can go wrong and possible ways to work around that. Or maybe you did not mean this to be according to [answer]. In that case please delete this.